# Микроразметка для контактов

Tags: html, css, микроразметка

Ка сделать микроразметку для списка с контактами

```html
   <ol class="contacts_list">
    <li><a href="#" ><img src="img/skype.png" alt="" />skypecontact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ><img src="img/telegram.png" alt="" />telegramcontact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ><img src="img/whatsup.png" alt="" />whatsupcontact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ><img src="img/icq.png" alt="" />icqcontact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ><img src="img/gmail.png" alt="" />emailcontact</a></li>
 </ol>
```

Comment: Ну а в чём Ваша проблема?

Comment: Не знаю как написать на пример для телеграма и скайпа. Для почты и телефона знаю.

Comment: Это не микроразметка. А ссылки.....

Answer (score 2):

```html
<ol class="contacts_list">
  <li>
    <a href="skype:nickname"><img src="img/skype.png" alt="" />skypecontact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="tg://resolve?domain=nickname"><img src="img/telegram.png" alt="" />telegramcontact (пользователь)</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="tg://join?invite=invite_link"><img src="img/telegram.png" alt="" />telegramcontact (группа)</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://wa.me/номер_телефона"><img src="img/whatsup.png" alt="" />whatsupcontact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.icq.com/whitepages/cmd.php?uin=id_пользователя&action=сообщение"><img src="img/icq.png" alt="" />icqcontact</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="mailto:test@test.ru"><img src="img/gmail.png" alt="" />emailcontact</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Это разве микроразметка?

Comment: @Denis, да, это просто ссылки (со своими протоколами в некоторых случаях). Тот, кто задавал вопрос, имел в виду это, назвав "микроразметкой".

Comment: @VladimirGonchar  Denis именно тот кто и задавал этот вопрос :D